# A second operation was started ... (But there is no parallel access)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a userRepo which holds my users data. Over night I check if the display names of the users changed. In the task scheduler class I am only using the the userRepository context in the functions below and I quite don't understand how I get a second operation exception in the SaveChangesAsync() Function.

Am I missing somethings if the context is not called over the Web-API instead its called internally from my task scheduler class?

This is the repository class

```
public class UserRepository
{
    private RTBMContext context;
    public UserRepository(RTBMContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public async Task<TUser> Update(TUser entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var item = await context.TUsers.FindAsync(entity.PkUserNt);
        this.context.Entry(item).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
        await this.context.SaveChangesAsync(); //Crash !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        return entity;
    }
}




public partial class RTBMContext : DbContext
{
    public RTBMContext(DbContextOptions<RTBMContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

...
```

Startup class:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Register DbContext
        services.AddDbContextPool<Models.RTBMContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseNpgsql(this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection"));
        });
        // Repository registration
        services.AddScoped<UserRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<TaskScheduler>();

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        TaskScheduler _siteService = serviceProvider.GetService<TaskScheduler>();
        _siteService.Run();
    }
```

And this is the scheduler that uses it

```
public class TaskScheduler : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserRepository userRepository;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory;

    public TaskScheduler(UserRepository userRepository, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    public void Run() //run at startup for debugging purpose
    {
        Thread threadRunAt2_O_Clock = new Thread(delegate ()
        {
            this.UpdateAllUserDisplayNames().Wait();
        });
        threadRunAt2_O_Clock.IsBackground = true;
        threadRunAt2_O_Clock.Start();
    }

    protected async Task<bool> UpdateAllUserDisplayNames()
    {
        List<TUser> allUsers = (await this.userRepository.GetAll()).ToList();
        foreach (TUser user in allUsers)
        {
            string newDisplayName = this.GetDisplayName(user.PkUserNt);
            if (newDisplayName != "" && newDisplayName != user.Name)
            {
                user.Name = newDisplayName;
                await this.userRepository.Update(user);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Exception:

> A second operation was started on this context before a previous
> operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads
> concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more
> information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.

Comment: It's impossible to say what's going on since there's no DbContext-related code here. We can't guess what those repositories do. There's a lot of unneeded and highly suspicious code thous - `IServiceScopeFactory`? A blocking thread *in a controller* that calls `UpdateAllUserDisplayNames`? What's the point of all this? In fact, what's the point of using those repositories? A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work already, that supports asynchronous operations. All changes are cached and persisted when `SaveChangesAsync` is called.

Comment: `(await this.userRepository.GetAll()).ToList();` is unexpected too. If you want to load some objects with EF Core, use `ToListAsync()`. Filter the objects in the query, not *after* loading the entire table. Once all objects are modified, a call to `SaveChangesAsync` should be made. If that `userRepository.Update(user)` calls `SaveChangesAsync` itself, it's a bug. One that could easily perform 42 DELETE and 100 INSERTs, because `SaveChanges` persists *all* changes, not just the latest one

Comment: You shouldn't be scheduling tasks like this anyway, use a proper library like Hangfire, I suspect all your problems will go away if you do that.

Comment: It's also impossible to tell what scope you have used to inject your repository. For example, if it's a singleton, that could also give you the same problems.

Comment: If you want to schedule a long running or periodic job you need to create a [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) at least, or use a purpose-built scheduling library like HangFire or Coravel. A controller lives only as long as a request does. It already uses a scope, so there's no need for `IServiceScopeFactory`.  If you call `Run` multiple times you end up with uncontrollable threads that probably call the same DbContext instance.

Comment: I suspect that if you post the code for `GetDisplayName` it will be easier to post an answer that shows how to correctly modify the names on a schedule than it is to fix the "repository" and the controller. It's quite likely that a simple `UPDATE WHERE` would do the job

Comment: Your task scheduler must be registered as a Singlenton instead of scoped

Comment: Why are you using `AddDbContextPool` instead of `AddDbContext`? This is only meant for *high-traffic* scenarios. Executing an `UPDATE` job on a timer isn't high-traffic. Worse, you're calling `Run` for the first time inside `ConfigureServices`, without a scope. If you call `Run` again you'll probably end up with the same DbContext instance

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro the problem is that the same DbContext instance is used in different threads. Using a singleton will make things *worse*. There are way too many things wrong with this code. Simply changing a non-Controller controller to a Singleton won't make it work as a task scheduler

Comment: As a side note there is already a [`TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler) class in the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace. So defining an identically named class that does something else could be a source of confusion.